# Web template WSP works on sharepoint foundation 2013 but not showing up in office 365

Tags: office-365

Web template WSP works on share-point foundation 2013 but not showing up in office 365.

What could be the possible reason ?

I can activate the wsp and also can activate the feature. I also tried to go through all available tempaltes using a script but template is not there.

Comment: also i cannot see listview webpart in office 365

Comment: i also tried this https://spminwebtemplate.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest but it doesn't appears too

Comment: Since you can see the feature in the o365 site the wsp is deployed properly. Can you verify that by any chance did the WebTemplate module got excluded from that feature.Just to check.Also look for any changes if you have made any after it was deployed to ur 2013 on premise

Comment: module ? do we use modules on office 365 for web templates, please provide me an example if you can. thank you

Comment: @customezed when you use web template in sharepoint online, the web template is deployed as a module. Please check whether the feature has that web template inside it.

Comment: nope i didnot added that, any tutorial i cannont find using module

Comment: you dnt have to add module explicitly..the VS Webtemplate itself is the module.i was asking you to check whether it is present inside that feature

Comment: Is it a newly created webtemplate in 2013 or a 2010 template? Could you post the xml of the webtemplate?

Comment: newly created in 2013 for office 365, ok i will

Comment: Is there an event receiver attached to the Feature? Elements.xml would also give some useful info.

Comment: Do you have `UIVersion="15"` set in the `onet.xml` file?  Try [this](http://styledpoint.com/blog/how-to-deploy-a-web-template-in-sharepoint-2013-online-and-on-premise/) site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if web templates are actually supported in office 365 or not, but there is a work around your problem, use SharePoint designer or browser to make changes to a web, then save it as a template, this will give you a .wsp file.

Import this wsp file in visual studio 2012, only select the web templates and it's modules, make changes to it and re-deploy it.

If your web template is not too much customized then use browser to customize it and save it as a template, it should save the template to be used in future as well.

Answer (score 1):

Let me guess...you are deploying directly from Visual Studio, which activates the features for you on deployment.

In O365 when you upload a WSP you need to explicitly activate the feature.  Go to site collection features and activate it.

Comment: nope, in visual studio you cannot remotely deploy to sites, so its not even possible, thanks for help suggestion

Comment: sorry, no, I mean you are deploying to your Foundation environment - the one that works - from Visual Studio. In O365 you have no option but to upload it yourself. Have you activated the Feature in your O365 site?

Comment: yup, activated the feature

Comment: i created a new site collection and uploadded the wsp and it works on it, so it's just office 365

Answer (score 1):

The major problem in saving web templates in an on premise environment is that not all features are available in Office 365 and vice versa. If you save a site as a template all the feature ID from an on premise SharePoint Installation will be stored in the WSP.

In addition this also causes trouble if you like to move templates across farms.

The problem is not really new an Rene Modery created a script that let you cleanup the WSP to be able to deploy it to the cloud and from the cloud back to an on premise.
[Cleanup Templates using PowerShell](http://modery.net/powershell-script-office-365-site-template-updater/)